# GoogleTV quick search box suggestions only showing 1 entry

Tags: google-tv, android-searchmanager, android-qsb

I am trying to get the global quick search box in googletv to show me all my custom suggestions.
When running my app on the latest googleTV emulator, the Global QSB shows me all the appropriate custom Suggestions; however running the same app on a GTV device , the global QSB only shows me the first custom suggestion but not the rest.
I have set my content provider to return the following data:
_id,
suggest_text_1,
suggest_text_2,
suggest_intent_data
suggest_intent_extra_data

any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which GTV device are you using? Also what build is it on?

Comment: It looks like Sony devices (nsz-gt1 & gs7) on the latest build show that behavior. A hi-sense pulse shows the suggestions appropriately, however it seems that that hisense does not implement the standard GTV search because a short click on the remote search button shows the app specific search and long click shows the global search.

Comment: Is there any code you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I checked with the team and it appears the emulator is not behaving correctly.

We only return the top result from the search provider, not all of them. This is a change we made from stock Android QSB.

Comment: Actually not many other results, 2 - 3 in most cases ; however in some cases my app provides the only result and it only shows under the more result but shows only the first suggestion on the list. Is the rule to show only the first result under "more results"?

Comment: @Krispy How can I apply for access to the google tv partner program?

Comment: Let's take this offsite - send me an email @google.com (same username) and we can discuss